# apk file crashes after the splash screen appears

Tags: kivy, apk, google-colaboratory, kivymd, buildozer

Hello everyone i am building an application file using buildozer in google-colab but after the successful building of the application file and after the splash screen appears my app shutdown can you all please help me with some solution for my problem
if you all need the python code or buildozer.spec file please let me know and please help me with this problem it is taking all my time.

```
expecting some solutions for my problem

these are the dependencies that i am using for building my app

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
import requests
import re
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton, MDIconButton
from kivy.uix.image import Image as KivyImage
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
import os
import string
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio
import wave
from kivy.core.window import`` Window
from kivy.clock import Clock

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.